# Model of database management systems

Tags: query, management

Having just installed MYSQL server and client on my laptop with Ubuntu, I was wondering,

(1) do all database management systems use the server-client model, regardless of whether they are actually used for websites together with webservers, or just for non-website usage such as beginner's study.

(2) Do query languages belong to the client of database management systems? I.e., are query languages used only on the client side of database management systems?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) No, see [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) for example.

(2) Not at all, as far as I know the SQL statements are parsed and processed server-side in every major client-server RDBMs.